# How to save which group a country is assigned to?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I got two tables in my DB:

```
countries ( id, name )
groups ( group_id, name, countries )
```

If I got USA, Canada, Germany and Holland in countries and want to group them like this in groups:

```
USA, Canada = North America
Germany, Holland = Europe
USA, Canada, Germnay, Holland = The World
```

How can and will I save this in my DB?
How can I save the same country in more then one group?
Had there only been one group per country it would have been easy by simply adding group_id in countries.

Thanks in advance,
Mikael

Comment: Make a junction table like group_countries which holds the group_id and country_id so there will be multiple entries for same country id with different group ids

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes you don't think longer then the rope are long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example database design:

```
CREATE TABLE Countries
    (`id` INT auto_increment primary key , `name` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO Countries
    (`name`)
VALUES
 ('Germany'),('USA'),('Holland'),('Canada')

;

CREATE TABLE Groups_Countries   
(`id` INT auto_increment primary key , Countries_ID int, Groups_id int)
;

INSERT INTO Groups_Countries
    (Countries_id,Groups_id)
VALUES
 (2,1),(4,1),(1,2),(3,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3)    
;



CREATE TABLE Groups 
(`id` INT auto_increment primary key , `name` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO Groups
    (`name`)
VALUES
 ('North America'),('Europe'),('The World') 
;
```

SQL query

```
SELECT c.name FROM Countries c 
JOIN Groups_Countries gc
ON c.ID = gc.countries_ID
JOIN Groups g
ON g.id = gc.Groups_ID
WHERE g.name = 'North America';

SELECT c.name FROM Countries c 
JOIN Groups_Countries gc
ON c.ID = gc.countries_ID
JOIN Groups g
ON g.id = gc.Groups_ID
WHERE g.name = 'Europe';

SELECT c.name FROM Countries c 
JOIN Groups_Countries gc
ON c.ID = gc.countries_ID
JOIN Groups g
ON g.id = gc.Groups_ID
WHERE g.name = 'The World';
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74372/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a many to many relationship. In relational databases this is represented by an associative table, which has (at least) two columns -

```
country_groups ( country_id, group_id )
```

Then, when it comes to make queries, you will include joins to bring in this table, eg for all countries in North America:

```
SELECT c.name FROM countries c
  INNER JOIN country_groups cg ON cg.country_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN groups g ON cg.group_id = g.group_id
  WHERE g.name = 'North America'
```